Why does crontab entry with process substitution not run?
Why does the first entry not run?
* * * * * cat <(date) >>~/output1.txt
* * * * * echo $(date) >>~/output2.txt

Expected current date in both output1.txt and output2.txt. Only got output2.txt.
The second entry with command substitution works. Why not the entry with process substitution?
crontab -n does not report any syntax errors.

Process substitution is a Bash-specific feature, so it requires Bash to run. cron traditionally uses sh.
(It doesn't work even when sh is bash, since process substitution is disabled in bash's compatibility mode)
To save yourself the trouble of this and other surprising crontab behaviors (like the interpretation of percentage signs), put your commands in a script file with the proper shebang, and have your crontab invoke that instead.
